# I have few question in PHP, Please tell me

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, salt

I have few PHP questions:

1) Is `password_hash()` full safe or I should use a `salt, pepper` or create own hashing alghoritm? and if `hash` is not secure How I convert it to a salt with hash manner to create strong algorithm?
Because I never made salt yet? Please tell me the short code in php.

2) What is better and safer `reCaptcha v2` or `reCaptcha v3`?

3) Is good to check is user logged with `$_SESSION['logged'] = true` or it is risky?

4) How to check is website full safe, resistant to attacks and it hasn't got any errors?

5) If i make something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<?php
require_once 'head.php';
?>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Will be website correctly indexed by Google?

6) How to increment website SEO?

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: Please ask just one question at a time.

Comment: Questions about SEO are not appropriate here. [webmasters.se] is a more appropriate place.

Comment: @Barmar This is simple question sir..

Comment: It's 6 questions. How will you decide which to accept if people answer different parts?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what to do, go look for a php package on packagist.org. This one looks good enough: https://packagist.org/packages/delight-im/auth

for 4 use unit testing: PHPunit is the standard nowadays.

Worry about 5 and 6 after you have built and successfully hosted the website.